# Is it worth killing the dragon on the bridge in Undead Burg?

Tags: dark-souls

I've just beaten the *Taurus Daemon* in *Undead Burg* and after that encountered a bridge guarded by a red dragon and some *Hollow Warriors*. I've found a way to sneak under the bridge through a stairway around the middle of the bridge.

From this point, I can fire arrow and hurt the dragon, and it doesn't seems to be able to hit me back. With my bow and arrows, I deal around 15 hit point at a time. Can I kill the dragon this way? If yes, how many hit points do the dragon have (so that I can estimate how many arrow I need for this)?

What will be the reward?

Should I just continue on my journey, and eventually the dragon will move aside and allow me to cross the bridge?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Bridge Wyvern is the official name of this dragon. As far as I know, it will never re-locate and will impede your passage on one end of the bridge or the other.

On the first playthrough, the Wyvern has 2208 HP. It would take you a while to pelt him down with arrows, but it is viable. If you're only doing 15 damage, it might be a good idea to check you meet the minimum stat requirements of the bow you're using as there's a damage and attack speed penalty if your parameters are lower.

That being said, the Bridge Wyvern is highly prone to glitching, and dying as a result. As mentioned on the **Dark Souls Wiki**, here are some methods of causing him to glitch and die, as well as how to safely kill him with arrows:

---

Ways to kill the Hellkite Wyvern without endangering your character:

- Shoot the wyvern from below the bridge with an arrow and use heavy
  soul arrow when it lands on the bridge and turns around to cause a
  glitch death. (may have been/should be patched soon)
- Shoot the wyvern from above and behind it after you gain access to the Black Knight's bridge tower (located above 3 plague rats) to
  cause a glitch death. (Hellkite Wyvern may or may not appear due to
  glitch. Exit area/zone and re-enter. It may be necessary to go as far
  as the Darkroot Garden to get it to come back)
- Shoot the wyvern from under the bridge; first cutting off the tail then shooting the head/neck. At base stats needed for the Short
  Bow (purchased for 1,000 souls from Undead Merchant (Male)) it will
  take roughly 350-400 arrows to take him down.

---

There are numerous other ways that the dragon could glitch and die. I have also caused it to glitch during soul farming - I would repeatedly trigger his fire attack to kill the enemies on the bridge and go back to the nearest bonfire to reset the monsters.

In terms of rewards - You receive 10,000 souls for his death. If you keep shooting his tail, it will eventually be cut off and you'll be rewarded with the **Drake Sword**, a 200 damage base sword that is good for starters. I suggest doing this before killing him.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that killing the bridge wyvern robs you of an easy 555 soul grind point next to a bonfire. In retrospect, I should have left him where he was for a while longer.

Comment: As of patch 1.05 the wyvern has the ability to heal itself for a large portion of its health once its health drops below an unspecified level, so plinking it with the shortbow is no longer feasible aside from acquiring the drake sword: http://darksouls.wiki.fextralife.com/The+Bridge+Wyvern

Answer (score -1):

I shot his tail off with a single shot from the dragon bow using dragon arrows from under the bridge, and then a few shots from the dragon bow to actually kill him. I have no problem killing him again as needed and getting more souls for free

Answer (score -2):

You can also shoot him once from the top of the stairs. You won't need armor equipped or a shield. I did it naked so I would be faster. Immediately equip your melee weapon 2handed. Run out and hit him once in the head and roll back into the stairwell. Do not lock on. At some point in your playthrough you will want to get rid of him. I did use him to farm 555 points method but reached a point where farming that small amount of souls wasn't worth it. At low levels, you definitely want to use the 555 soul farming method. Take one step onto the bridge and then beat it back down the stairs. He wipes all the enemies on the bridge. Then you run back down to the bonfire down the ladder and reset. It is tedious but the souls add up pretty fast when you are at low level. - JD